# How to run the Python script in the command prompt so it gets run in the command prompt, not in PyCharm Edu?

Tags: python, command-line, pycharm

I installed Pycharm Edu a while ago, but now I need Python scripts to be executed in the command prompt. However, when I enter the Python file's name in the command prompt in the following order, the code opens in PyCharm Edu.

```
C:\Users\my_name\Folder1\Python for Everybody\Week 7>loops1.py
```

How can I stop the file from opening in PyCharm Edu and execute it in the command prompt?

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Try including the python command `python loops1.py`, without it Windows is likely opening the file in the program set as the default handler for `*.py` files

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I also realized that by right-clicking and choosing the files to "Always open with Python", I can run them in the command line without them being opened in PyCharm.